# Angular 5 - Avoid multiple calls for asset images

Tags: angular, image, performance, webpack, angular-cli

In an angular application (version 5.1.0, with angular-cli and webpack) I have a country selector component where the user can select a country from a drop down or writing the name in an autocomplete field. For each matching result, the relative country and flag image is proposed:
[image: s]

All the images are stored in an `asset` folder in the application (src/assets/flags/).
The first time the page with the component is loaded a GET call is executed for each image flag, slowing down the first page load.

Is there any best practice within the *angular environment* I could adopt to improve this?

Possible solutions I have in mind are to build an image sprite or avoid to provide all images since the beginning and display only the matching results after 3 digits, for instance, in the autocomplete field.

**Component template**

```
<mat-autocomplete #panel="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="selected($event, country)" *ngFor="let country of filteredCountries | async" [value]="country">
      <div class="selector-elements">
        <span>
            <img [src]="country.imageUrl" width="24" height="24" /> 
        </span>    {{ country.name }}
        </div>
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say it’s not necessarily an Angular best practice. It’s web application so a request being made by Angular, React or any other technology should have the same basic principle: optimize the way of fetching content for the page.

For your scenario I would definitely recommend the use of a sprite, as you mentioned.

Comment: thanks for your answer, indeed reducing server calls is always an approach to follow. In my question I was asking whether there is any "construct" from Angular that might help in my case.

Comment: By the way are you aware of this? This might save you some time https://github.com/flarik/css-sprite-flags

Comment: I use different/styled images, but thanks for the link, I will definitively have a look at it.